# Warped and wobbly sounds from my Crosley record player

Tags: turntables

3 or 4 years ago my girlfriend bought a Crosley Cruiser turntable.  But due to a lot of family illness, we'd never got round to setting it up and using it, so we attempted to do that this week.

The belt was off, so we followed the YouTube video and successfully got the belt back on and it looks taut round the spindle.

But when we play a record, it sounds very slightly off, like every few seconds it sounds like it runs at a slightly slower speed for a few seconds.

Somewhere online it suggested turning the turntable manually (with the power off) 20-25 times and we've done that.

As we watch the record, it appears to be wobbly, but looking at the LP, it's not warped.

Do you have any advice on what might be the issue with the speed that the record is played at?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a HiFi equipment issue & nothing to do with music practise or theory. There is nowhere on Stack Exchange for this type of question; you need to refer it to the manufacturer or a repair shop.

Comment: Sorry, this site is mainly about making music, not about listening to music.